# How to detect and list all unique class-names (and ids) inside an .erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, aptana

I want to detect and prepare a list of unique class names that are being used inside a given view. Is there a way to do it, apart from manual **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>** search in Aptana/Rubymine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can

```
$.unique($('*').map(function(i, e){return $(e).attr('id')}))
```

and for classes

```
$.unique($('*').map(function(i, e){return $(e).attr('class').split(' ')}))
```

Note that the jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/ says that "unique()" does only work on jQuery objects but we are using it here with strings. I just tried it on the stackoverflow site though and it seems to work.